# How to access a Render variable from the client (NODEJS + PUG)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
exports.nuevoproyectoPST= async (req, res)=>{
    const proyectos = await Proyectos.findAll();

    //console.log(req.body);
    const {nombre} = req.body;
    let errores=[];

    if (!nombre){
        errores.push({'texto':'Falta agregar algo'})
    }

    if (errores.length > 0) {
        res.render('nuevo-proyecto', {
            title: 'Nuevo Proyecto',
            errores,
            proyectos
        });
    } else {
        await Proyectos.create({ nombre });
        res.redirect(req.originalUrl);
    }


}
```

How can I access **errors** from the client
I want to access errors from a js (public/js/app.js)
and from that js place an if errors swal.fire

I want to access errors from the client side using a JavaScript file (app.js) to display a SweetAlert notification if errors are detected.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `errores` variable on the client within your `public/js/app.js` file, you'll need to pass it from your Node.js server to your PUG template and then make it available to your JavaScript.

Here’s how you can do this:

1. Pass the `errores` array to the PUG template as you are already doing.
2. In your PUG template, you will need to include a script tag that creates a JavaScript variable from the `errores` variable. This can done by setting a global JavaScript variable in a  tag within the PUG file.

For example, in your PUG template, you could do something like this:

```
script.
  var errores = !{JSON.stringify(errores)};
```

The `!` before `{JSON.stringify(errores)}` tells Pug to not escape the HTML, effectively allowing you to insert raw JavaScript into your template. Be careful with this to avoid injection vulnerabilities.

Then, in `public/js/app.js`, you can check the `errores`variable:

```
if (errores && errores.length > 0) {
  const errorMessages = errores.map(error => error.texto).join('\n');

  swal.fire({
    title: 'Error',
    text: errorMessages,
    icon: 'error',
    confirmButtonText: 'OK'
  });
}
```

Make sure that `app.js` is included after the inline script in your PUG template, so the `errores` variable is already defined when `app.js` runs.

If there are cases where `errores` might not be defined, you should also include a check (as in the code above) to see if `errores` is defined before trying to access its properties.

Comment: if (typeof errores !== 'undefined') ?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. The difference is that `if (typeof errores !== 'undefined')` checks only for `errores` not being `undefined`, whereas `if (errores)` checks if `errores` is truthy (which implies it's not `undefined`, `null`, `false` etc...)